# GEKKO Python - simple linear regression from Documentation

Tags: python, regression, gekko

By following GEKKO documentation I used the example for the linear and polynomial regression. Here is just the part regarding the simple linear regression.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

xm = np.array([0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.8])
ym = np.array([0.52,0.53,0.4,0.6,1.01])
             
#### Solution
m = GEKKO()
m.options.IMODE=2
# coefficients
c = [m.FV(value=0) for i in range(2)]
c[0].STATUS=1
c[1].STATUS=1

x = m.Param(value=xm)
yd = m.Param(value=ym)

y = m.CV(value=ym)
y.FSTATUS = 1

######### uncomment ############
#y = m.Var()
#m.Minimize((y-yd)**2)
################################
# polynomial model

m.Equation(y==c[0]+c[1]*x)
# linear regression
m.solve(disp=False)
p1 = [c[1].value[0],c[0].value[0]]
p1
```

I just wonder why the different results are obtained when uncommenting the lines

```
y = m.Var()
m.Minimize((y-yd)**2)
```

It seems that the results obtained (linear, quadratic, cubic) in the documentation are not the least squares ones. What the minimizing criteria was used in those cases?

Best Regards,
Radovan

Answer (score 1):

Switch to `m.options.EV_TYPE=2` to get a [squared error objective](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmEvType).

The default in Gekko is the l1-norm objective. Here is a [description](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EstimatorObjective) of the differences:

[image: Objective Function]

The l1-norm objective (sum of the absolute error) is less sensitive to outliers and bad data.